# Manually changing route in vue js 3 is causing problem

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vuejs3-composition-api, vuejs-routing

I have created **vue js** application. I don't have my own domain. I have hosted my code on two websites `vercel.com` and `netlify.com`. My code is working fine. But when I change any route by writing **url** manually, it shows `404 error'.
[Vue js route change problem 404 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxIvq.png)

I've tried many times but can't seem to fix it.

Comment: standard web server behavior is to serve HTML file matching the URL path.  With SPA, you only have one HTML page, so all paths must redirected to it.  Edit your vercel.json [following the documentation instructions](https://vercel.com/docs/projects/project-configuration#legacy-spa-fallback)